# Should I use an autowired static variable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to implement a singleton pattern with a caching feature. At first `MySingleton` was only a POJO and things were simple enough, but then I needed to add a new feature, which also required autowiring a bean. (`MyComponent` is really an interface to a data repository)

I put the `@Component` annotation on `MySingleton` to trigger the autowiring (even though it is always called a static way) and created a private constructor to pass the `MyComponent` reference to an object created by new. This code seems to work, although I do not fully understand why.

**My question: I feel like I'm doing it wrong, but am I?**
(would you approve this pull request to your code base?)

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
public class MySingletonTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertNotNull(MySingleton.getInstance().getMyComponent());
    }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MySingleton {

    private static final long CACHE_TIMEOUT = 60 * 60 * 1000; // 1 hour
    private static final AtomicReference<MySingleton> INSTANCE = new AtomicReference<MySingleton>();
    private final Calendar timestamp; // NOTE: this is NOT static!

    @Autowired
    private static MyComponent myComponent;

    private MySingleton(MyComponent myComponent) {
        this.timestamp = Calendar.getInstance();
        MySingleton.myComponent = myComponent; // I do not understand why this line is needed
    }

    private boolean isTimeout() {
        return Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - timestamp.getTimeInMillis() > CACHE_TIMEOUT;
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance() {
        if ( INSTANCE.get() == null || INSTANCE.get().isTimeout() ) {
            INSTANCE.set(new MySingleton(myComponent));
        }
        return INSTANCE.get();
    }

    public MyComponent getMyComponent() {
        return myComponent;
    }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyComponent {

}
```

Comment: if you use spring, a bean is by default a singleton (unless you give it prototype scope), so why do you need all your singleton logic?

Comment: Put logging into your constructor. You'll be surprised. There will be two instances.

Comment: @NirLevy That is an excellent point! I really don't need it.

I am in transition from Java EE to Spring and thought the `@Autowired` to be like `@Inject`. Today I learned it is not.

I just removed the cluttered code and annotated my initialization method with a `@PostConstruct` and everything worked as it should.

Cheers.

Comment: You cannot autowire a `static` variable so it would fail anyway.

Comment: @M.Deinum I agree, it should fail, but it dit not. The code example works. As talex pointed out, there are two instances and although it is a static variable it is not null when the second instance is tested.

Comment: It won't fail as it will be ignored and the reference will be `null`. However due to your init code it will be set nonetheless but not through spring.